# How to recover basic networking utilities on Debian?

Tags: networking

I am administrating a small server for LAN, providing basic services such as web-proxy, ldap, kerberos, afs, etc. Yesterday there was a power cut so server halted. When I restarted it no network interfaces were available and configured. I tried restarting networking daemon but it just exited with 0 status. So I tried to run one of the interfaces manually, but `ifup` and `ifdown` commands simply are not there. No only in PATH, but they disappeared from `/sbin`.

So my question is: how can I recover these network utilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any messages in `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/boot.log`, etc. indicating an I/O error or an error mounting a partition or an error activating LVM or MD or RAID?

Was there a "Filesystem unclean" or "fsck" message when the server powered up?

Are all partitions currently mounted?  Are there any files in `/sbin`?

To fix the exact problem you mention, assuming all partitions were correctly mounted, I would boot from a Debian boot CD in recovery/rescue mode, start a shell, find where your `/sbin` (or probably the `/` (root)) partition is mounted, then run `chroot <that path> /bin/bash`, then you can run `sudo apt-get install ifupdown` to re-install `/sbin/ifup`, then reboot.

But you should try to find out if anything else is broken.  Try installing `debsums`, i.e. `sudo apt-get install debsums`.

Comment: Great answer! I fixed the problem by simply reinstalling the `ifupdown` packages, but still don't know what exactly happened to it. No logs indicate any possible causes and another applications seem work finely...